# Name isn't included in my article's google scholar citation. All of my co-author's names however have been included

Tags: citations, authorship, google-scholar

There are 3 other co-authors, all of their names have been included in the citation. But my name hasn't been included. None of us have google scholar accounts, but only my name was excluded. However my name is included in the publishers 'suggestion citation' part and I'm included as an author there. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding, much of Google scholar citations are automated. I know folks who have shown up as cited in studies where they were not in fact cited. That said, I just tested this. If you create a profile, you can select articles that are yours, and you can edit these once they are associated with your profile. You can also manually input articles that you authored, which should address your issue in this question.

Comment: I did that, I made an account and selected the article, and also edited it to add my name as an author. But it still hasn't updated it. Like when I search for my article from the google scholar home page, I still don't see my name as an author.

Comment: @SaiCharanB, they've got some suggestions in their troubleshooting documentation. What you've described seems to be pointing to issues with their web crawls for inclusion. I'm unsure from their [documentation](https://scholar.google.com/intl/en/scholar/inclusion.html#troubleshooting) whether the publisher needs to reach out or if you do.